# I have a check box ,i want to set key value for that check box and send it to a json web service

Tags: java, android

I have a Check box, and I want to set a key value for that check box and send it to a web service. If the check box is checked it means I have to show one key, if unchecked means it has to show another key.

How can I do this?

```
CheckBox chalan_recvd=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chalan_recvd);
{
    if (chalan_recvd.isChecked()) {
        chalan_recvd.setChecked(true);
    } else { 
        chalan_recvd.setChecked(false);
    }
}
```

//My code for to sent the data in web service

String checkbox1=chalan_recvd.getText().toString();

```
    HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams,
            TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);

    HttpParams p = new BasicHttpParams();
```

p.setParameter("chalan_recvd",Util.removeSpace(checkbox1));

//Inside the Url

nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("chalan_recvd",  Util.removeSpace(checkbox1)));

Comment: Can you elaborate you problem???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing actually doesn't make any sense, since if the checkbox was checked, the value would have been `true` and if it wasn't, then it would have `false` anyways. Instead, you need to change your `if-else` condition to something like this.

```
// I hope this code snippet is present in the onCreate() method of the activity 
// which has the layout containing this CheckBox set
String key = null;
CheckBox chalan_recvd = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chalan_recvd);
if(chalan_recvd.isChecked()) {
    // Use the key 1 for your webservice
    key = "key1";
} else {
    // Use the key 2 for your webservice
    key = "key2";
}

// Now just send the key to your webservice
String checkbox1 = key;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean deciding_flag;
CheckBox chalan_recvd = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chalan_recvd);
{
     if (chalan_r`enter code here`ecvd.isChecked())
    {
        chalan_recvd.setChecked(true);
        deciding_flag = true;
        hashmap.put("key", deciding_flag);
    }
     else
        {
            chalan_recvd.setChecke`enter code here`d(false);
            deciding_flag = false;
        hashmap.put("key", deciding_flag);
        }
```

/*  here in hash map we are putting boolean value which is a flag and now while fetching the value if that flag value is true then that's your first value otherwise its second value. */